# How to get content of a web page (android)?

Tags: android

A web page:
- 5 first seconds. It shows an advertisement picture.
- After, its show main page.
If I get content by common way. It only gets page content with advertisement.
How to load main page content?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to scrape the advertisement page for the actual URL to the real page, and redirect there.

If you are lucky, it will be in a META-REFRESH tag. If your unlucky, it will be in javascript.

Comment: Hic it's in javascript. How can I do?